# (Microsoft SQL) How can I get items, with their hierarchically associated child items as a json value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchy

I have a table, items

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.items (
    item_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR,
);
```

I then have a table, kits, which shows which items are child items.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.kits (
    parent_item_id INT
    child_item_id INT
);
```

```
INSERT INTO items (id, name)
VALUES 
(1, "Rainy day kit"),
(2, "Beach day kit"),
(3, "Umbrella"),
(4, "Jacket"),
(5, "Swimsuit"),
(6, "Sunscreen"),
(7, "Rainy Beach day kit")
```

```
INSERT INTO kits (parent_item_id, child_item_id)
VALUES 
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(2, 5),
(2, 6),
(7, 1),
(7, 2);
```

I want to get a few items, with their children in json format. This query works great for getting an item with its child items

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.name, 
   (SELECT i2.item_id, i2.name 
    FROM items i2 
    INNER JOIN kits k on k.child_item_id = i2.item_id
    WHERE k.parent_item_id = i.item_id
    FOR JSON PATH
    )
FROM items i
WHERE i.item_id = 1
```

```
item_id, name, kit_children
1, "Rainy day kit", [{"item_id":3, "name":"Umbrella"},{"item_id":4, "name":"Jacket"}]
```

But if I want to recursively go deeper, this won't work. Does anyone know of a way to recursively get child items?
Such a query could return a result like this:

```
item_id, name, kit_children
7, "Rainy Beach day kit", [{"item_id":1, "name":"Rainy day kit", "kit_children":[{"item_id":3, "name":"Umbrella"},{"item_id":4, "name":"Jacket"}]}, {"item_id":2, "name":"Beach day kit", "kit_children":[{"item_id":5, "name":"Swimsuit"},{"item_id":6, "name":"Sunscreen"}]}]
```

Comment: Easiest way is a scalar function. Eg https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d8b17feee654977f459ed01b06ebf057